# Can we use Apache Kafka as a system for file watching

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

I have source path and destination path in HDFS.Our UpStream places files in source path and We check for any new files added in source path if there are any
we copy from source path to destination path.

For this right now we are using a shell script. But I want to use Kafka in between.I researched about it, found only HDFS sink connectors. There are no source connectors for HDFS.

My Question is can we use Kafka here and how?

Answer (score 0):

For this use case , I don't think you need kafka.
There are various ways to do this  , one way for example , you can use Zookeeper watcher interface which getters triggered on watched events and programmatically fire the copy to hadoop from your program

As an alternate, Hadoop 2.6 introduced DFSInotifyEventInputStream that you can use for this. You can get an instance of it from HdfsAdmin and then just call .take() or .poll() to get all the event and based on the event you can take action